# Which block of code in the kernel writes to /proc when new process is created/deleted?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I know that whenever a process is created/destroyed, a directory is created inside /proc which contains all information related to process which is dynamically updated.

I would like to know where in the kernel is the line of code which: 
1. Creates a directory (when a process is created)? 
2. Deletes the directory (when the process is destroyed)?

I assumed that this line would either be in "fork.c" or "exec.c" since they are the files responsible for creating new processes but i wasnt able to find functions like "proc_create()" or create_proc_entry().

3. Am i looking for the wrong function? or the wrong place?

Thanks!

Comment: The `/proc` filesystem code is under the `fs/proc` directory in the kernel source tree.

Answer (score 0):

It's done dynamically. For example, when you read the `/proc` directory, the running tasks are enumerated and an entry for each process is dynamically constructed if it doesn't already exist (see proc_root_readdir => proc_pid_readdir).

Likewise, if you attempt to read or traverse a `/proc/<PID>` directory, it's created on the fly if it doesn't already exist and the entries it needs are created on the fly as well (see proc_pid_lookup => proc_pid_instantiate).

When a process exits, the entries are generally removed via proc_flush_task (though actual removal can be delayed due to references being held by other processes).